# How do I change the RAM setting in VirtualBox?

Tags: macos, vagrant, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I work on a MacBook Air with 4GB of RAM. For my projects, I use Ubuntu in VirtualBox (by way of Vagrant). But my VMs have insufficient RAM. VirtualBox takes up most of the RAM (2GB). I can not change the limits, the slider does not work (it is frozen?).

[image: virtualbox]

Comment: This question has nothing to do with programming.  Ask on https://superuser.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do the following in your Vagrantfile

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  # ... other configuration

    config.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
      v.memory = 1024
    end
end
```

This will allow only 1GB on the VM.

Answer (score 0):

In your Virtual machine box conversationdriverlocal_default_1468940462492_81779 is running, need to be shutdown and than change the RAM from setting by sliding the slider and start the again.